# Hyper-V Virtual Fax Server in SBS 2008

Tags: hyper-v, windows-sbs-2008, fax

I'm trying to think of a way to enable us to use our SBS 2008 VM's Fax Server within Hyper-V.

I had immediately considered a simple USB Fax Modem but of course, for some reason, Hyper-V doesnt support USB devices. I've read about USB over Ethernet devices like AnywhereUSB and wondered if anyone could recommend either a product of this type, or an alternative solution to allow us to receive faxes within the SBS VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried to get this working, but here's the fruit of my research:

There are hardware and software solutions for USB over ethernet. I'm not quite sure how reliable they are. I've heard reports that they are really sensitive. You can always try it out and let us know how it goes. There is an open source solution available at http://usbip.sourceforge.net/

I've seen a success store of somebody getting this to work with SBS under Hyper V: http://www.usb-over-network.com/usbnet-solutions/remote.html

If you find a modem that presents a com-style interface, you might be able to get this to work. It maps the com port on the host over the network to the guest machine:
http://www.goodjobsucking.com/?p=214

Comment: You could probably find an oldschool fax modem that hooks up to a COM port on eBay. That's assuming your server HAS a COM port, otherwise you'll need a USB->COM adaptor and then expose that com port to Hyper-V

Comment: I'll accept this; and try it out since it does offer solutions. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, really, you can do what you want using "USB over Network" software. But if your modem is serial you can use this tool:
http://www.fabulatech.com/network-serial-port-kit.html